# How to handle struct that has a variable that points to another struct, that has a variable that points to another struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Say I need to create a struct that holds information for a unit (class at university/school etc). I then have a struct that holds information a student, that attends multiple units, so he will have a pointer to this Unit struct. I then have another struct that holds all of these student structs (say a school struct).

Eg:

```
typedef struct unit {
    int code;
    float mark;
} Unit;

typedef struct student {
    Unit* listofunits;
    int numofunits;
    char name[50];
} Student;

typedef struct record {
    Student *listofstudents[];
    int numofstudents;
} Record;
```

Few questions:

1. How many asterixes do i appoint to listofstudents and listofunits
2. When Malloc'ing these, can it be done like this?

> ```
> Record *recordarray = (Record*)malloc(sizeof(Record));
>
> recordarray->listofstudents = (Student*)malloc((recordarray->numofstudents)*sizeof(Student));
>
> recordarray->listofstudents->listofunits = (Unit*)malloc((recordarray->listofstudents->numofunits)*sizeof(Unit));
> ```

3. To access the Unit struct, is it done like this:

> recordarray[i][j].code;
>
> recordarray[i][j].mark;

Comment: `listofstudents` is an empty array of pointers. That's not valid. You already have it correct in the `student` structure with its `listofunits` member.

Comment: so do i have both 'listofstudents' and 'listofunits' the same structure as 'listofunits'?
and how do i access these units? (eg dereference)

Comment: OT: In C There Is No Need To Cast `void`-Pointers.

Comment: Think twice: Why do you suffix `listofstudents` with `[]`, as you do not do this for `listofunits`.

Comment: This `recordarray[i][j].code;` is a 2D-addressing. There is nothing 2D-dimensional in the code you show.

Comment: would someone be able to give me an example of accessing variables in the unit struct?

Comment: This `Record *recordarray = (Record*)malloc(sizeof(Record));` allocated exactly one `Record`: So to het the mark of zth unit of the yth student do: `recordarray[0].listofstudents[y].listofunits[z].mark`. The assumes `y<numofstudents` and `z<numofunits` for the yth student.

Comment: excellent, thank you!